# Validate IP Address

Tags: python, string, list

I am trying to validate if the string of numbers is valid IP address or not.

There are mere 2 logics that i am using as shown in code-

- The length of `ipnos` should be 4 after the `split('.')`
- The strings should be numbers only.

But looks like it is NOT giving me correct result.

For ip='123.456.78.09' : It should result `True` but it returning `False`

```
def validate(ip):
  ipnos=ip.split('.')
  validnos=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
  false_counter=0

  if len(ipnos) != 4:
    false_counter+=1

  for sublist in ipnos:
    for nos in range(len(sublist)):
      if sublist[nos] not in validnos:
        false_counter+=1

  
  if false_counter>0:
    return False
  else:
    return True

ip='123.456.78.09'
validate(ip)
```

Comment: Feed it into the `ipaddress` module. And BTW that's not a valid IP address.

Comment: `validate('12345.0.0.0')` = `True` per your logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `sublist[nos]` is `<class 'str'>`, not `<class 'int'>`.

So, you should change the `validnos` to next to fix it:

```
validnos=['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']
```